# pairwise swap (Python, Pandas, NumPy)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a data frame like this:

```
ID, side, col

10, home, a_h
10, away, a_a
11, home, b_h
11, away, b_a
...
```

I want to swap the values `a_h` and `a_a`,  `b_h` and `b_a` and make a data frame like this:

```
ID, side, col

10, home, a_a
10, away, a_h
11, home, b_a
11, away, b_h
...
```

I could implement this by using for-loop but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it using numpy or pandas.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a bit more context to the size of your dataframe and the number of pairs you are intending to swap? Even adding pseudo code for the intended for loop you mentioned would give us some insight.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear enough. Based on my data, @rafaelc 's code is what I wanted to do. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

```
df['shift_col'] = df.groupby('ID').col.transform(np.roll, shift=1)
```

---

```
ID side shift_col

10 home  a_a
10 away  a_h
11 home  b_a
11 away  b_h
```

Comment: @rafaelc I don't think your answer addresses pairwise swapping as in the original question... If I'm understanding np.roll, this is only intended for shifting values (which is only useful if the a_a and a_h, & b_a and b_h are ordered and conveniently adjacent to each other.)

Comment: The idea is that when you `groupby.apply`, the function is applied to the `col` Series in every group. Each group has 2 items - home and away - and when you `roll` them, you simply swap their positions. `np.roll` works differently than `pd.Series.shift` because it fills the first values with the last values

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `groupby` reverse the order  then assign it back

```
df['col']=df.groupby('ID',sort=False).col.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[::-1]).values

df

Out[104]: 
   ID  side  col
0  10  home  a_a
1  10  away  a_h
2  11  home  b_a
3  11  away  b_h
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: `df['col'] = df['col'].replace({'a_h': 'a_a', 'a_a': 'a_h'})` and `df['col'] = df['col'].replace({'b_h': 'b_a', 'b_a': 'b_h'})`. More on replace() here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: What if you have 100000 rows? Would you have to manually create your dictionary ?

Comment: @rafaelc this solution holds if there are 100000 rows. The dictionary scales as the number of pairs to swap scales, not with the number of rows in the dataframe.

Comment: I know it works. But are you going to *manually* write 1000000 entries in a dictionary?

Comment: _The dictionary scales as the number of pairs to swap scales, not with the number of rows in the dataframe._ There are only two pairs to swap.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I say hahaha. You have manually written `{'a_h': 'a_a', 'a_a': 'a_h'}` and then `{'b_h': 'b_a', 'b_a': 'b_h'}`. Suppose you also have `c_h`, `d_h`, `e_h`, `f_h`, `g_h` all the way through `z_h`. And then, when it gets to `z_h`, it starts over from `a_i`, then `b_i`, then `c_i` etc. Are you **manually** going to **write every** dictionary with two pairs to swap and call **manually** replace on all of them? Because that is obviously a solution that doesn't scale

Comment: No I understand that; and yes you would have to manually write every entry for the dictionary. But OP didn't specify how many pairs to swap. And from the example, I assumed it was just two. If it is in fact just two, this works and is easier than a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

**IFF** this is truly a pairwise swap and the DataFrame is sorted so that IDs have exactly two observations that appear in consecutive rows, we can use two shifts and slice the proper rows from each.

```
df['shift_col'] = pd.concat([df['col'].shift()[1::2], df['col'].shift(-1)[::2]])
#   ID  side  col shift_col
#0  10  home  a_h       a_a
#1  10  away  a_a       a_h
#2  11  home  b_h       b_a
#3  11  away  b_a       b_h
```

The benefit here is that with many `IDs` this will scale much better than `GroupBy.apply`. The downside is that it's error prone.